# Access Chrome APIs in a web application built with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I am creating a web application in ReactJS, and I want to access Chrome APIs such as **chrome.proxy**, **chrome.management**, and **chrome.tabs** in my web application.

```
function App() {
  const onProxyConnect = () => {
    chrome.proxy.settings.get((details)=>{
      console.log({details}) //proxy details
    })
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={onProxyConnect}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Not possible. In Chrome the app can send a message to a chrome extension's [onMessageExternal listener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage) in the background script so that it will call the API. In Both Chrome and Firefox the app can send a DOM CustomEvent to the content script of an extension running in the page so that it will send another message to its background script that will call the API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.